# How to echo the result array from PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
    $pages = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE slug = startpage');

    $pages->execute();

    $resultarray = array();

      while($row = $pages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $resultarray[] = $row;
      }
```

I'm trying to do this because I want to use the array in the whole document, not just inside the while. See below example:

```
    //Somewhere outside of the while loop    
    <h1><?php echo $resultarray['header']?></h1>
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* instead of the 'while' loop you can use 'fetchAll' */
/* you can use 'while' if the values need to be processed */
$rows = $pages->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/* the final variable will contain all rows */
echo $rows[0]['header'];
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><?php echo $resultarray[$i]['header']?></h1>
```

Here `$i` is a index of the `$resultarray` array.

Answer (score 0):

dont forget that you have multidimensional array, so for the first row you can access value:

```
$resultarray[0]['header']
```

Comment: Ah, that's why. Is there a way to circumvent the requirement to specify the `[0]`?

Comment: if you are sure that query returns just 1 row.. change code to `$resultarray = $row;` then you will be able to access to value like this `$resultarray['header']`